# UnZip zip file and access the files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zip

How can I unzip a .zip file and store it at a client site for further process using JavaScript without a network call?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript library for Zip and Unzip files.

https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/fs-api.html